# Is there a way to change a css style of an external script?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have an external script running on one of my pages -

```
<script type="text/javascript">var opt={id:829,cnt:3,bg:''};(function(){var script=document.createElement("script");script.type="text/javascript";script.async=true;script.src="https://kvr.ru/js/widget/api.js?id=829";document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(script);})();</script>
```

when I insert it in my page I get an ugly looking vertical scrollbar.

I've changed some css values via firebug, and its helps, but how I override the css that script gets?

I want to change **font-size** in following css from external code:

```
p.info-widget, p.info-widget a{
color:#959595;
font-size:10px;
margin:0 1px 0 0;
text-align:right;
```

}

I've tried to insert  p.info-widget  into my main.css, and override its font-size with !important, but it doesn't work(

Comment: show some more CSS and the HTML where its aimed for

Comment: Well is your selector more specific than the styles the script outputs?

Comment: Look at this link, it might help. http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_howto.asp

Comment: put this into the java script : document.getElementById("Your id").style.fontSize = "size";
note: this works in firefox.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add or include your css after that script's css, as it will override it.

For example, if your external css has:

```
p.info-widget, p.info-widget a{
color:#959595;
font-size:10px;
margin:0 1px 0 0;
text-align:right;
}
```

You can override that css by including this after it.

```
p.info-widget, p.info-widget a{
color:#2e2e2e; // changed color
font-size:10px;
margin:0 1px 0 0;
text-align:right;
}
```